# react-native AAPT: error: attribute android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback not found

Tags: android, react-native

I recently upgraded to react-native 0.69.5 and getting the following error in Android Studio while running the app on Android

```
ERROR:/Users/username/Projects/myapp-monorepo/packages/MyApp/android/app/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:80: AAPT: error: attribute android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback not found.
```

This attribute is already present in the AndroidManifest.xml and set to true.

How can I fix this error?